# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'profile_percentage' cannot be null on doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm trying to set a default value to profile_percentage field on the yml file this way

```
...
....
profilePercentage:
            type: float
            column: profile_percentage
            nullable: false
            options:
                comment: Profile surveys completed percentage
                default: 0
```

In order to avoid to set the field manually

```
$client->setProfilePercentage(0.0);
```

But with this configuration I get this message:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'profile_percentage' cannot be null
```

Comment: What does the code inside `setProfilePercentage` look like?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript,its only a setter,abd is working, the reason of my question is why I have to call a setter if I've setted a default value on the yml file?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript,there is no type,its working ,the problem its  why I have to use this function if there is  a default value for the field profile_percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default values aren't 100% portable, the safest way to do it in doctrine is in entity constructor.

Comment: Or, if it’s a static value, on the class property.